# Browserify, shims are broken?

Tags: gulp, browserify

There are many great things about using browserify, except one: Substack and maintainers of the project keep changing and breaking existing functionality, making it crazy difficult to upgrade.

Once again I've tried to upgrade and once again seems I'm gonna need to have to fallback to ver.4.2, because I can't make it work. I've tried to use ver.7.0 - and already had to downgrade to 6.1.0, because watchify breaks with 7.
Now, even with 6.1.0 I can't make shims work. Can you guys tell me the correct way of using shims now? I used to use `browserify-shim` transform, but it seems to be broken.

Should I put transform into `package.json` or it's still possible to cal it from `Gulpfile`? like:

```
.transform({ globals:true },'browserify-shim')  
 // I've tried both - globals:true and globals:false - still won't work
```

Please someone, show me the correct configuration and use with Gulp, that compatible with 6.1.0

It builds the project fine, yet it still fails in the browser, saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current [Browserify documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts) shows the signature as `b.transform(tr, opts={})`, e.g. `transform('browserify-shim', {globals: true})`. What happens if you try that?

And, are you sure you want to apply that globally? If not, but you need it applied to files that are not "top-level", specifying the transform in a `package.json` is one solution.

Comment: I've managed to fix the build by removing all  "depends" sections. Somehow it now figures the right order without those

Comment: Are you talking about gulp task dependencies? In any case, is your question still relevant?

Comment: no I'm talking about "browserify-shim" section of package.json.

Comment: Ok, do you still have the question posted here?

Comment: Well, I can't delete it, since you answered it :) I'll just mark it as the right answer. Although I've tried your solution and didn't work